# ELIF utilizando not in, dentro de um FOR

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de refinar o ELIF dentro de um FOR, para que não entre nele sempre que a data não existir, mas sim se aquela data especifica não existir.

Segue o problema:

Para cada data encontro

```
{%for u in i.chamada_set.get.datas_encontros.filter|dictsort:"data_ano"%}
```

Entra no para cada data finalizada

```
{% for a in i.chamada_set.get.finalizada_set.filter %}
```

E verifica se:

```
{%if a.data_finalizada|date:"d, m, Y" == u.data_ano|date:"d, m, Y"%}
```

A data finalizada é igual a data encontro, porém, se eu possuir 3 datas finalizadas, apenas 1 cairia nesse if e as outras 2 no else

Então pensei no ELIF

```
{%elif u.data_ano|date:"d, m, Y" not in a.data_finalizada|date:"d, m, Y" %}
```

Porém continou entrando pois as outras datas finalizadas, não são iguais a data encontro.

Imagem:

[image: elif]

Em verde são as datas finalizadas, na Pessoa Um, tem as seguinte ordem de data finalizada [06/11/2018, 08/11/2018, 13/11/2018]

A ideia principal seria mostrar que não encontrou a data, e funciona quando tem apenas uma finalizada (Pessoa Dois e Pessoa Tres).

Código da TR:

```
{% for y in i.chamada_set.get.alunos.filter %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{y.nome_aluno}} {{y.sobrenome_aluno}} </td>
    <td>{{y.cgu_aluno}}</td>
    {% for u in i.chamada_set.get.datas_encontros.filter|dictsort:"data_ano"%}
        {% for a in i.chamada_set.get.finalizada_set.filter %}
            {%if a.data_finalizada|date:"d, m, Y" == u.data_ano|date:"d, m, Y" and y.id == a.aluno_finalizado.id %}
                <td style="color:green">
                    <i class="">encontrou </i>
                    <i class="">{{u.data_ano|date:"d, m, Y"}}</i>
                </td>
            {%elif u.data_ano|date:"d, m, Y" not in a.data_finalizada|date:"d, m, Y" and y.id == a.aluno_finalizado.id  %}
                <td  style="color:tomato">
                    <i class="">não é a data: </i>
                    <i class="">{{u.data_ano|date:"d, m, Y"}}</i>
                </td>
            {%endif%}
        {%endfor%}
    {%endfor%}
    </tr>
{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Retirei esta parte da documentação do Jinja2: [Template Designer Documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/)

> Unlike in Python, it’s not possible to break or continue in a loop.
>   You can, however, filter the sequence during iteration, which allows
>   you to skip items. The following example skips all the users which are
>   hidden:
>
> ```
> {% for user in users if not user.hidden %}
>     <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
> {% endfor %}
> ```

Uma dica que pode ajudar é utilizar o index do for como contador para lhe ajudar a escapar no if.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei esta outra informação que pode ajudar muito. O For nao tem break mas o if sim. da uma olhada se isso lhe ajuda

[Link da docucmentação](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#loop-controls)

> ### Loop Controls
>
> If the application enables the Loop Controls, it’s
> possible to use break and continue in loops. When break is reached,
> the loop is terminated; if continue is reached, the processing is
> stopped and continues with the next iteration.
>
> Here’s a loop that skips every second item:
>
> ```
> {% for user in users %}
>     {%- if loop.index is even %}{% continue %}{% endif %}
>     ... {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> Likewise, a loop that stops processing after the 10th iteration:
>
> ```
> {% for user in users %}
>     {%- if loop.index >= 10 %}{% break %}{% endif %} 
> {%- endfor %}
> ```
>
> Note that loop.index starts with 1, and loop.index0 starts with 0